# PHP script not loading that hosted in xampp

Tags: php, html, mysql, browser, xampp

I have a small website host in the xampp. I am using the latest version of the xampp for this.but when I enter the URL on the web browser, that php page not loading at all.other pages are loading without any problem.here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Industrious by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>

<head>
    <title>ARTIK Cloud based Smart Parking System</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />

    <style>
        rainbowParking {
            display: block;
            background-color: #dddddd;
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 70px;
            line-height: 60%;
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 40px;
            border-style: groove;
        }

        indigoParking {
            display: block;
            background-color: #dddddd;
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 70px;
            line-height: 60%;
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 40px;
            border-style: groove;
        }

        div.container {
            margin: 15px;
        }

        div.left,
        div.right {
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        div.left {
            background-color: white;
            width: 900px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        div.right {
            background-color: #dddddd;
            width: 360px;
            height: 400px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        div.right-output {
            background-color: #dddddd;
            width: 360px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        .myBox {
  position:absolute;
  left:471px;
  top:94px;
  width:204px;
  height:183px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=90);
  opacity:0.90;
  z-index:7;
}

.redBox {
  background: red;
}

.greenBox {
  background: green;
}


.square-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: blue;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-top: 100%;
    }
}

.square-content {
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    color: white;

    div {
       display: table;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
    }

    span {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white
    }
}


    </style>
</head>

<body class="is-preload" >

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html">SmartPark</a>
        <nav>
            <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="links">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="websocket.html">Parking Lot Status</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="generic.html">Parking Space Availability</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Heading -->
    <div id="heading">
        <h1>ARTIK Cloud based Smart Parking System</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Main -->
    <section id="main" class="wrapper">

        <h2 style="color:green;text-align:center;font-size: 50px">Main Parking Status</h2>

        <div class="container">


<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'smart_parking';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 1234;

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
   $link,
   $host,
   $user,
   $password,
   $db,
   $port
);


//List the Columns for the Report 
echo "<table border='1'> 
<tr> 
<th>Sensor ID</th> 
<th>Slot Status</th> 
</tr>"; 

$result = mysql_query($success,"SELECT sensorId,slotStatus,time FROM arduino_ultrasonic au1 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM arduino_ultrasonic au2 WHERE au1.sensorId = au2.sensorId)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['sensorId'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['slotStatus'] . "</td>"; 
  if($row['sensorId']=='Ultra_sensor_01' && $row['slotStatus']=='Occupied') // [val1] can be 'approved'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>".$row['slotStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['sensorId']=='Ultra_sensor_01' && $row['slotStatus']=='Free')// [val2]can be 'rejected'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #008000;'>".$row['slotStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['sensorId']=='Ultra_sensor_02' && $row['slotStatus']=='Occupied')// [val2]can be 'rejected'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>".$row['slotStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['sensorId']=='Ultra_sensor_02' && $row['slotStatus']=='Free')// [val2]can be 'rejected'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #008000;'>".$row['slotStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['sensorId']=='Ultra_sensor_03' && $row['slotStatus']=='Occupied')// [val2]can be 'rejected'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>".$row['slotStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['sensorId']=='Ultra_sensor_03' && $row['slotStatus']=='Free')// [val2]can be 'rejected'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #008000;'>".$row['slotStatus']."</td>";  
  echo "</tr>"; 
  } 
echo "</table>";  
$mysqli->close();
?>

            </div>


    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                <section>
                    <h3>SHU Final Year Project</h3>
                    <p>This project is based on the IoT concept. I used Raspberry Pi, Arduino and Samsung Artik cloud service to create this project.
                        This a simple demonstrantion of upcoming smart parking.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h4>Links</h4>
                    <ul class="alt">
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://raspberrypi.org">Raspberry Pi</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://arduino.cc">Arduino</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.artik.io/">Samsung Artik</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h4>Social Media Links</h4>
                    <ul class="plain">
                        <li>
                            <a href="www.twitter.com">
                                <i class="icon fa-twitter">&nbsp;</i>Twitter</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="www.facebook.com">
                                <i class="icon fa-facebook">&nbsp;</i>Facebook</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="www.instagram.com">
                                <i class="icon fa-instagram">&nbsp;</i>Instagram</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="www.github.com">
                                <i class="icon fa-github">&nbsp;</i>Github</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright">
                &copy; CheshanJ. Photos:
                <a href="https://unsplash.co">Unsplash</a>, Video:
                <a href="https://coverr.co">Coverr</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I used mysqli for the SQL part. if you wondering about the SQL query, that is for selecting the latest record.
Anyone can advise on this?please share if there any.Thanks in advance.

P.S: There is this error also occuring:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartParking\slotstatus.php:192 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartParking\slotstatus.php on line 192
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated in PHP 5 and was removed completely in PHP 7. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you running ? mysql has been depreciated.

Change from **mysql to mysqli** in your code

You code still seems to have mysql, check !

```
    $result = mysql_query($success,"SELECT sensorId,slotStatus,time FROM arduino_ultrasonic au1 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM arduino_ultrasonic au2 WHERE au1.sensorId = au2.sensorId)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: I am using PHP 7.2.6. So I think I have to follow your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error message states that you're making a call using `mysql_query`  mysql_query has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Instead try;

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
```

Comment: I tried the solution. then there is error :

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartParking\slotstatus.php:208 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartParking\slotstatus.php on line 208`

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_array(),  new versions of PHP don't support 'mysql' functions.